# Is it possible to close the notification bar created by swaynag by using a command line?

Tags: desktop-environment, notifications, sway

I use swaynag to create a notification as a bar on the top of the screen, for example:

```
swaynag -m "my message"
```

I can then close the notification, by moving the mouse over the "x" on the right end of the bar and clicking it.
But sometimes that fails to respond. Is it possible to close the notification bar by using a command line? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
pkill swaynag
```

works by killing the swaynag process that hangs around.